# NameError: name 'Key' is not defined

Tags: python, function, return-value, nameerror, defined

I am getting a NameError, when trying to call in def Password() saying that 'Key' is not defined. When clearly I have defined it in the RandomKey(): function and returned the value... How do I fix it?

```
def RandomKey():

            Main_Key = random.randint(1,25) 
            Key = Main_Key
            return Key 

def Password():
            while T:
                    pass_code = (int(input('Enter The Key: '))) 

                    if pass_code == Key and User_Menu_Input == 2:
                          time.sleep(.3) 
                          print('Key recognized... Transfering to the Encryption Menu') 
                          Timer(Time)
                          ReadFile() 
                          break
                    elif pass_code == Key and User_Menu_Input == 3:
                          time.sleep(.3) 
                          print('Key Correct... Transfering to Decryption Menu') 
                          Timer(Time) 
                          Decrypt() 
                          break

                    else:
                            print('Key Not Recognized... Try Again!')
```

Comment: _When clearly I have defined it in the RandomKey(): function_ Yes, but if it is not a global variable, the `Password` function can't see it. Do a search for "python variable scope". One option is to pass it as an argument to the `RandomKey` function.

Comment: You have a function `RandomKey` which returns a value but you've not shown where you've called said function and whether you've stored the returned value or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course Key is not defined in reason it's private var in other function. You can fix it with 1000 variations. In first one try this

```
Key = RandomKey()
if pass_code == Key
```